# Ocean's Twelve hotel scene with Saul's card having problem?

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-twelve

In the movie Ocean's Twelve:

> **Waiter:** There appears to be a slight problem with your card.
>
> **Saul:** Oh, well, yes. Here.
>
> **Waiter:** I'm afraid not, sir.
>
> **Saul:** Why?
>
> **Waiter:** Your business manager said you would understand.
>
> **Saul:** Todd said I would understand?
>
> **Waiter:** No, Mr. Benedict.
>
> **Saul:** Mr. Benedict. Mr....Oh, yes. An old friend, a practical joker.
>         Tell Mr. Benedict, he's won this round, yes.

What exactly does the waiter mean by  **"Your business manager said you would understand"**?

Comment: I think he's just repeating Benerdict's words "He'll understand", which is a way for him to say that he's found him and know what he has done (rob him).

Answer (score 6):

Like [Larme](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/3489/larme) said, the waiter just repeated what he had been told.

Benedict informed the restaurant that he was Saul's business manager, that the credit cards were invalid, and that Saul would understand why the cards were invalid.

As it turns out, he was right. Saul immediately understood Benedict had caught him. He just played out the situation as if it was some practical joke, disguising the panic he was feeling.